# Dealing with Option and Either types - idiomatic conversions?

Tags: scala, idioms

I'm probably missing something that's right in the documentation, but I can't really make much sense of it - I've been teaching myself Scala mostly by trial and error.

Given a function `f: A => C`, what is the **idiomatic** way to perform the following conversions?

`Either[A, B] -> Either[C, B]`

`Either[B, A] -> Either[B, C]`

(If I have two such functions and want to convert both sides, can I do it all at once or should I apply the idiom twice sequentially?)

`Option[A] -> Option[C]`

(I have a feeling that this is supposed to use `for (...) yield` somehow; I'm probably just blanking on it, and will feel silly when I see an answer)

And what *exactly* is a "projection" of an `Either`, anyway?

Comment: From a comment below you seem to be confusing `Either` with a `Pair`, a `Tuple2`. That is not the case: an `Either` can only contain _one_ value. In a sense, it is similar to `union` in C, except that you know which member is actually stored.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I still get confused one projections are thrown into the mix. I didn't really express that one clearly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You do either a:

```
either.left.map(f)
```

or a:

```
either.right.map(f)
```

You can also use a for-comprehension: `for (x <- either.left) yield f(x)`

Here's a more concrete example of doing a `map` on an `Either[Boolean, Int]`:

```
scala> val either: Either[Boolean, Int] = Right(5)
either: Either[Boolean, Int] = Right(5)

scala> val e2 = either.right.map(_ > 0)
either: Either[Boolean, Boolean] = Right(true)

scala> e2.left.map(!_)
either: Either[Boolean, Boolean] = Right(true)
```

EDIT:

How does it work? Say you have an `Either[A, B]`. Calling `left` or `right` creates a `LeftProjection` or a `RightProjection` object that is a wrapper that holds the `Either[A, B]` object.

For the `left` wrapper, a subsequent `map` with a function `f: A => C` is applied to transform the `Either[A, B]` to `Either[C, B]`. It does so by using pattern matching under the hood to check if `Either` is actually a `Left`. If it is, it creates a new `Left[C, B]`. If not, it just changes creates a new `Right[C, B]` with the same underlying value.

And vice versa for the `right` wrapper. Effectively, saying `either.right.map(f)` means - if the either (`Either[A, B]`) object holds a `Right` value, map it. Otherwise, leave it as is, but change the type `B` of the either object as if you've mapped it.

So technically, these projections are mere wrappers. Semantically, they are a way of saying that you are doing something that assumes that the value stored in the `Either` object is either `Left` or `Right`. If this assumption is wrong, the mapping does nothing, but the type parameters are changed accordingly.

Comment: Break down how this works for me, please? Something to do with the projections? Evidently `.left` and `.right` here are not like in other languages with library "pair" types, where they would just access the members of type [A] and [B] respectively.

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain a little bit of what happens under the hood. But, either is not a pair, or a tuple type, also called an intersection type - `A x B`. It holds either a member of type [A] or [B] - `A V B`. This means that you cannot safely access either member, like you could in a tuple, because only one member is present.

Comment: ... Beautiful. And how about with an Option? Just `for (x <- option) yield f(x)`, since the Option is already iterable?

Comment: @Karl `Option` is not an `Iterable`, but it implements the method `map`, so that is enough.

Comment: The problem here is that you would need to provide 2 mapping functions to do the actual mapping of an `Either`, since there are 2 possible *types* of values inside, and you don't know which it is. You could do: `e.left.map(!_).right.map(_ * 2)`. Could you go for loop style from that. Maybe. Let me think about it..

Comment: With `Option` you have only possible value that could be mapped - and only one *type* for the mapping function. Here you have 2 of them - hence, you need 2 mapping functions.

Answer (score 3):

Given `f: A=>B` and `xOpt: Option[A]`, `xOpt map f` produces the `Option[B]` you need.

Given `f: A=>B` and `xOrY: Either[A, C]`, `xOrY.left.map(f)` produces the `Either` you are looking for, mapping just the first component; similarly you can deal with `RightProjection` of `Either`.

If you have two functions, you can define mapping for both components, `xOrY.fold(f, g)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
val e1:Either[String, Long] = Right(1)
val e2:Either[Int,Boolean] = e1.left.map(_.size).right.map( _ >1 )
// e2: Either[Int,Boolean] = Right(false)
```